# How to copy a function by value?

Tags: functions, assignment

I need to change a function symbol multiple times by assigning another symbol to it, but when I'm trying to do that the symbols overwrite each other.

I'm assuming this is because the assignment is by reference.

For example, this input:

```
func1[x_] := x^2
func2 = func1; func3[x_] := func1[x]
{func1, func2, func3}
{func1[#], func2[#], func3[#]} &[4]
func1[x_] := -x
{func1[#], func2[#], func3[#]} &[4]
```

Gives the following output:

```
Out[]= {func1, func1, func3}
Out[]= {16, 16, 16}
Out[]= {-4, -4, -4}
```

How could I make the assignment so changing one function doesn't influence changing the other?

Comment: it might well not be the right choice for your problem, but I think you should be aware that for those cases where you treat a function as an object, using `Function`s is often more appropriate than downvalue-definitions. When using `func1=Function[x,x^2]` for the  first definition and `func1=Function[x,-x]` for the second your example will work as you want...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [DownValues](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html) (see [second Application](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html#subOuter2)), with a [transformation rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html).

Using your code, this input:

```
In[345]:= func1[x_] := x^2
DownValues[func2] = DownValues[func1] /. func1 -> func2;
func3[x_] := func1[x]
{func1, func2, func3}
{func1[#], func2[#], func3[#]} &[4]
func1[x_] := -x
{func1[#], func2[#], func3[#]} &[4]
```

Gives the following output:

```
Out[348]= {func1, func2, func3}
Out[349]= {16, 16, 16}
Out[351]= {-4, 16, -4}
```

Comment: Nice first answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to do it is

```
func2[x_] = func1[x];
```

then

```
func1[x_] := x^2
func2[x_] = func1[x];
{func1, func2}
{func1[#], func2[#]} &[4]
func1[x_] := -x
{func1[#], func2[#]} &[4]
```

gives

> ```
> {func1, func2}
> {16, 16}
> {-4, 16}
> ```

Here are links to two valuable answers highly relevant to your problem, [Understand what Set (=) really does](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18456/3066) and [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/3066)

Comment: If you have also `func1[4] := False` this is not copied to `func2`, and if you have *only* `func1[4] := False` then `func2` refers to `func1`, so if `func1` is cleared `func2` does nothing.